# Как исправить этот баг aiogram?

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу бота на aiogram, но у меня проблема. Для вызова кнопок у меня такое условие, text="текст". Но если человек сам напишет текст, то оно все равно отработает. Как сделать чтобы оно не отработало?
Ч - человек
Б - бот
Ч: нажимает на кнопку "Зайти" и выполняется действие
Ч: пишет "Зайти" и тоже выполняется действие и мне надо чтобы выполнялось, только в том случае если он нажмет на нее

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Никак, если вы про ReplyKeyboard. Однако если вы перейдете на InlineKeyboard то будет проще